# "I am living in Berlin" (it's been 30 years)

Tags: present-tense

Would a native speaker say "I am living in Berlin" instead of "I live in Berlin"  if it's not their hometown and they have been living there for 30 years and they are still living there?

Comment: I wouldn't. I'd use it if I was planning to leave Berlin at some point though. "I am living in Berlin at the moment/until this contract finishes." If I'd been living there for 30 years and intended to stay, then I'd say "I live in Berlin" and would maybe add "but I'm from X originally".

Comment: Only speakers of "Indian English" (people who say ***I am wanting*** something rather than ***I want it***) would be likely to use the progressive aspect in your context. [Here's a "German-based" exploration](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/3793/Schubert_exam.pdf?sequence=1) of this "non-mainstream" syntactic feature.

Comment: (But a native speaker might well use ***Present Perfect** Continuous* to say something like ***I've been living** in Berlin for 30 years*.)

Comment: https://painintheenglish.com/case/578.  It's mentioned here. Maybe it wasn't written by a native speaker.